# Grafana negative spikes in latency query

Tags: apache-kafka, prometheus, grafana, metrics

I have a Grafana dashboard that is measuring latency of a Kafka topic per partition in minutes using this query here:

`avg by (topic, consumergroup, environment, partition)(kafka_consumer_lag_millis{environment="production",topic="topic.name",consumergroup="consumer.group.name"}) / 1000 / 60`

The graph is working fine but we're seeing negative spikes in the graph that doesn't make a lot of sense to us.  Does anyone know potentially what could be causing these spikes?

[image]

Comment: Are you able to show a graph? Even with axis removed for confidentiality it might be informative. Do you also see the negative results when you graph just ‘kafka_consumer_lag_millis’? (I would expect so?)

Comment: @AshleyDavies I added a graph with the private information hidden.  You can see on the blue like which is out partition 2 that there are negative dips in the latency.  You are correct, we also see a negative value when just graphing 'kafka_consumer_lag_millis'

Comment: So the fact that `kafka_consumer_lag_millis` itself has negative data suggests this is a Kafka/underlying server issue rather than a Prometheus/Grafana one -- your graph is correct, and it's highly unlikely Prometheus is doing something to the data post-consumption. With that in mind, my naive guess is that the time on your Kafka server is out of sync with the time on wherever the lag is measured against, so sometimes messages seem to arrive, but are sent after current time because of the time sync issue

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a guess than an accurate answer based [here](https://github.com/yahoo/CMAK#consumerproducer-lag). let's suppose in a very simple manner we have 2 metrics being measured, and their subtraction is the number sent to prometheus:

```
lag = offset-producer - offset-consumer
```

while the producer offset is measured with a pooling mechanism, the consumer offset is measured with direct synchronous requests (to whatever other inner place has this values). this way, we could have outdated values for the producer. example:

```
instant  | producer | consumer
t1       | 10       | 0
t2       | 30       | 15
t3       | 200      | 70
```

if we had always updated values, we should have:

```
instant | lag
t1      | 10 - 0   = 10
t2      | 30 - 15  = 15
t3      | 200 - 70 = 130
```

let's suppose our offset producer was one measurement behind on t2 due to the long pooling period:

```
l(t1) = p(t1) - c(t1)
l(t2) = p(t1) - c(t2)
l(t3) = p(t2) - c(t3)
```

this would produce:

```
instant | lag
t1      | 10 - 0  = 10
t2      | 10 - 15 = -5
t3      | 30 - 70 = -40
```

and there's your negative value: when the diff increases and your pooling rate of the positive value is bigger than prometheus' pooling rate, you get the negative value to be bigger than older positive value.

now to really answer your question we need to check prometheus' kafka client code to check if the pooling rate is editable to make it smaller until negative values vanish (or instead just set it smaller than prometheus rate directly)